# How to launch mysql persistent on openshift OKD?

Tags: kubernetes, mariadb, persistence, openshift-origin, okd

I am unable to launch mysql deployment with persistent storage, the ephemeral one works fine. I am getting the following error.

I tried launching deployment from cli and web console as well. In both cases I get the following error.

```
=> sourcing http://20-validate-variables.sh  ...
=> sourcing http://25-validate-replication-variables.sh  ...
=> sourcing http://30-base-config.sh  ...
---> 01:27:23     Processing basic MySQL configuration files ...
=> sourcing http://60-replication-config.sh  ...
=> sourcing http://70-s2i-config.sh  ...
---> 01:27:23     Processing additional arbitrary  MySQL configuration provided by s2i ...
=> sourcing 10-mysql57.cnf ...
=> sourcing 40-paas.cnf ...
=> sourcing 50-my-tuning.cnf ...
---> 01:27:23     Initializing database ...
---> 01:27:24     Running /opt/rh/rh-mysql57/root/usr/libexec/mysqld --initialize --datadir=/var/lib/mysql/data --ignore-db-dir=lost+found
---> 01:27:24     Starting MySQL server with disabled networking ...
---> 01:27:24     Waiting for MySQL to start ...
2019-03-30T01:27:24.466755Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-03-30T01:27:24.584395Z 0 [Note] /opt/rh/rh-mysql57/root/usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.24) starting as process 40 ...
2019-03-30T01:27:24.774993Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-03-30T01:27:24.775057Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-03-30T01:27:24.775068Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-03-30T01:27:24.775075Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-03-30T01:27:24.775761Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2019-03-30T01:27:24.775809Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-03-30T01:27:24.777416Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-03-30T01:27:24.778012Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-03-30T01:27:24.784562Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-03-30T01:27:24.841105Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-03-30T01:27:24.852695Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-03-30T01:27:25.019343Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Header page consists of zero bytes in datafile: ./ibdata1, Space ID:0, Flags: 0. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html …  for how to resolve the issue.
2019-03-30T01:27:25.019422Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Corrupted page [page id: space=0, page number=0] of datafile './ibdata1' could not be found in the doublewrite buffer.
2019-03-30T01:27:25.019473Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption
---> 01:27:25     Waiting for MySQL to start ...
2019-03-30T01:27:25.520693Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2019-03-30T01:27:25.520749Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-03-30T01:27:25.520763Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2019-03-30T01:27:25.520772Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-03-30T01:27:25.521120Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-03-30T01:27:25.521862Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2019-03-30T01:27:25.530469Z 0 [Note] /opt/rh/rh-mysql57/root/usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```